# Getting DNS Cache in vb.net and returning domains

Tags: vb.net

What's the best way to get the DNS Cache in Visual Basic and returning recently resolved domains? I only need the domains to compare them whit a list.

```
Function GetDnsCache()
    Dim DNSCache As New Process
    DNSCache.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig"
    DNSCache.StartInfo.Arguments = "/displaydns "
    DNSCache.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    DNSCache.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    DNSCache.
    DNSCache.Start()

    MsgBox(DNSCache.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
    DNSCache.WaitForExit()
End Function
```

This is not the cleanest way of doing this and it also takes ages to parse and load.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. It executes `ipconfig /displaydns` and appends the output to a file. Then, the file is read line by line and displayed wherever you want (I've used a Listbox)

```
Dim Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Shell.run("cmd /c ipconfig /displaydns >> C:\ipconfig.txt")

Using reader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\ipconfig.txt")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim currentLine As String = reader.ReadLine()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(currentLine)
    End While
End Using
```

Should you like to display the info into a MsgBox...

```
Dim Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Shell.run("cmd /c ipconfig /displaydns >> C:\ipconfig.txt")
Dim reader as As New IO.StreamReader("C:\ipconfig.txt")
MsgBox(reader.ReadToEnd.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

Comment: `ipconfig` doesn't provide a parameter for showing what you're looking for. It shows the whole DNS info when using `/displaydns`. I'm afraid you'll need to modify the output in order to erase whatever is not a domain name.